# Wordpress Menu + Bootstrap + Glyphicon Instead Text

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm working on a Wordpress site with Bootstrap.
I'm using Bootstrap's navbar for the menu integrated with WP.
I have my homepage as a link in the navbar as "home".
Instead of "Home" as a text I want a glyphicon to appear and not text.
I think I could use CSS for that... something like this:

```
#menu-item-55 {
  /* something that removes text and adds the icon */
}
```

But in bootstrap I have to use the icons like this

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
```

Anyone?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured that I can do it by adding a custom link and putting the  inside the navigation label.

I still would like another way to do it. :D

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the wordpress 3+ wp_nav_menu with your theme adding this snippet to the `functions.php` will add a glyphicon-home link of bootstrap to your navigation.

```
function addHomeMenuLink($menuItems, $args)
{
    if('header_menu' == $args->theme_location) // make sure to give the right theme location for the menu
    {
        if ( is_front_page() )
            $class = 'class="current-menu-item active"';
        else
            $class = '';
        $homeMenuItem = '<li ' . $class . '>' .
                $args->before .
                '<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" href="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" title="Home">' .
                $args->link_before .
             /* 'HOME' . //add home text if you want. */
                $args->link_after .
                '</a>' .
                $args->after .
                '</li>';
        $menuItems = $homeMenuItem . $menuItems;
    }
    return $menuItems;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'addHomeMenuLink', 10, 2 );
```

[source](http://reigelgallarde.me/programming/wordpress-bootstrap-glyphicons-home/)

Answer (score -1):

1. Navigate to Appearance > Menus
2. Find the menu item that you want to add an icon to
3. Expand the menu item
4. Inside the Navigation Item you will want to add your icon code either before or after or in place of your existing menu item label. For this example I’m going to use the home icon. Here’s what you would type:

   < i class='icon-home icon-white'>< /i> Home

*Note: Make sure to use single quotes!*

5.Important: This is something you want to make sure to do, it could negatively impact your SEO if you ignore this step.  You will want to make sure to put the plain text in the Title Attribute field.

6.Save the menu. (Also make sure you have selected one of the menus from the Theme Locations drop downs) That’s it!

http://jasonbradley.me/icons-in-the-wordpress-menu/

Comment: Menu items *really* shouldn’t have HTML in them. What happens if the original poster removes Bootstrap/Glyphicons? He’s stuck with the HTML in the menus.

Comment: If removes Bootstrap/Glyphicons nothing happens, the <i> tags is empty, nothing will be shown on browser.

Comment: Of course, this is not the optimal way. But you should know the tags anytime can be removed from nav title as they had been added from admin panel.